# Как сделать несколько способов валидирования yii2 формы

Tags: php, yii2, form

К примеру у нас 4 поля и все required, если я выбрал способ оплаты 1 то остаются только 2 required поля, а если способ 2, то появляются остальные 4 required поля

Вот модель:

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "orders".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $sum
 * @property string $deliver
 * @property string $pay
 * @property string $fio
 * @property string $mail
 * @property string $phone
 * @property string $city
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $localindex
 * @property string $comment
 * @property string $date
 * @property integer $status
 */
class Orders extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'orders';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['sum', 'deliver', 'pay', 'fio', 'mail', 'phone', 'city', 'address', 'localindex', 'comment', 'date', 'status'], 'required'],
            [['fio', 'mail', 'comment'], 'string'],
            [['status'], 'integer'],
            [['sum', 'deliver', 'pay', 'phone', 'city', 'address', 'localindex', 'date'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'sum' => 'Sum',
            'deliver' => 'Deliver',
            'pay' => 'Pay',
            'fio' => 'Fio',
            'mail' => 'Mail',
            'phone' => 'Phone',
            'city' => 'City',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'localindex' => 'Localindex',
            'comment' => 'Comment',
            'date' => 'Date',
            'status' => 'Status',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй валидацию required when:

```
[['fienld1', 'field2'], 'required', 'when' => function () {
    return $this->type === 1;
}],
[['fienld3', 'field4'], 'required', 'when' => function () {
    return $this->type === 2;
}],
```

Если необходимо вообще игнорировать атрибуты в зависимости от типа, то лучше использовать сценарии:

можно запилить сеттер где будет автоматом добавляться к модели сценарий:

```
public function setType (int $type)
{
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->setScenario(self::getScanarioByType($type));
}

protected static function getScanarioByType(int $type): string
{
    return $type === 1 ? self::SCENARIO_ONE : self::SCENARIO_TWO;
}
```

а в валидаторах просто указать:

```
[['field1', 'field2'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_ONE],
[['field3', 'field4'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_TWO],
```

ну и атрибуты в сценарии можно перечислить:

```
public function scanarios(): array
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_ONE => ['field1', 'field2'],
        self::SCENARIO_TWO => ['field3', 'field4'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!